# What am I supposed to do with this review item?

Tags: support, flagging

I got a [review item](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13476/should-follow-up-be-promised-in-a-cover-letter) for "closed w/o comment (auto)". But this is my only option:

[image]

Am I supposed to just leave it as-is? I added a comment, but I still only have the option to flag/disagree. If I do nothing, won't the flag just disturb the next person to come along to the review queue?

Comment: I wondered the same thing, saw this in mine this morning

Comment: Was this in one of the review queues? Or the 10k tools?

Comment: Seeing as how I have 6k rep, it can't be 10k tools I don't think. There was a yellow circle next to my name which I clicked, and it brought me to that. It didn't say a queue name. I have no idea what it was.

Comment: @jmac On beta sites, the threshold for access to the 10k tools is 2k. It sounds like that's what this is.

Comment: This appeared for me as well...considering I am the person who flagged it.

Answer (score 3):

On beta sites, when a question is closed without any comments, Community automatically flags it for attention ([see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187715/167443)).

These flags have popped up in the flag queue from time to time (whenever this happens).

It seems the text of the flag has recently changed.

You can just leave it until a diamond mod dismisses it; I doubt anyone will be *too* disturbed by its presence.

Typically the two actions you could take in addition to flagging for attention or as invalid are close and delete:

- Close: It's already closed, so this option is not available.
- Delete: Posts with a score higher than -2 can't be voted for deletion until they've been [closed for two days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/167443), so this action isn't available.

Comment: So I should ignore that review queue? I find it odd that an item would pop up that the only action I can take is nothing...

Comment: @jmac See [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), although I doubt it will tell you anything you don't already know. It seems the only other actions you could take are close (already closed) and delete ([not eligible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/167443)).

Comment: Oh so "community is the one making those pesky and confusing flags! Hahahahaha, I've been curious about that for a while :)